# Upgrade CentOS 5.8 to newer version

Tags: centos, upgrade

I have actually a VServer running on CentOS 5.8

When i try

```
yum update
```

it stucks at this version and won't upgrade to any higher one.

Any solutions for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @dawud: That's not this. I think Michael wants to know why it isn't updated to latest version of Centos5 - version 5.9 - and it isn't receiving security updates.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1):

Vserver is not a full virtualization but a operating system level virtualization. It needs a special, unsupported by CentOS version of linux kernel on host, and it does not use a kernel at all on a guest.

Your provider may configure your guest to not run updates so it can use the same binaries for multiple guests, saving hard drive space. It irresponsible and dangerous to not install security updates though, so you should complain if that's the case.

You may be able to work around it, if your provider used modified `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` for disabling updates. You can install an original centos-release package from CentOS 5.9 in your guest. It would install original yum repositories in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo.rpmnew`, which you could use to replace `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and then try to update packages in your guest. **No warranty.**

I wouldn't recommend trying to update to CentOS 6 though. It would probably not be compatible with your host kernel.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible but ideally just install a fresh CentOS 6 box and copy files over.

Consider reading the following:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide/MigratingFiveToSix